# Unable to Generate Result_set from Stored procedure in c#

Tags: sql, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Temp Table return data from Stored procedure doesnot create Modal class in Entity c# and it returns int.
`Select Test 1,test2,test3,test4  from #temp1`

sql side working and get the as expected after adding this procedure to my entity frame work result set is not generating instead of class it is generating int class
Please suggest is anything wrong done from side.
And also suggest whether temp table returns Result columns in entity.

Comment: As a guess, when you say _"Modal class "_, you actually mean a `Model` class with an "e"?

Comment: Are you using the "Database First" concept with MS `Entity Framework`?

Comment: yes @StefanWuebbe

Comment: As another guess, you are probably not having an issue in context with the C# language Version 4.0 from 2010 as the `[c#-4.0] ` Tag would indicate?

Comment: Modal class is generated automatically with the return columns from procedure when we added that edmx in entity frame work in c# @StefanWuebbe

Comment: Currently SO does not let me edit your Question saying "Suggested Edit queue is full", but you as the question owner might be able to correct the "modal" typos and the misleading Tag, I guess. The better the Question, the better the Feedback usually

Comment: In addition, I'd guess readers could be interested to see what you exactly tried and what Errors you got, and also the difference between the new Stored Procedure that failed to get integrated with `EF` as opposed to previous SPs that you were able to handle successfully

Comment: I think stored procedures have to be imported to the model as a `function`  and then mapped to a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `SET FMTONLY OFF` in SP that will work